# AccessSQL - Can't get it to display properly... Trying to sort data

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm a beginner Programming student and nothing in my text book is helping me with this problem! I need to display these field names ProjectID, ProjectName, DepartmentPhone, EmployeeNumber, LastName, FirstName, EmployeePhone and also the field name Department.
The last field name is included in two separate tables so I used the WHERE clause to make it display.
However, I have to specifically display employees working on projects assigned by the 'Marketing' Department.
I can't get this to work... If I remove my current WHERE clause than Department will not work or display... But I think I need another Where clause to make it only display projects by the Marketing Department.

Here is my current code:

```
SELECT ProjectID, ProjectName, DepartmentPhone, EmployeeNumber, LastName, FirstName, EmployeePhone
FROM PROJECT, DEPARTMENT, EMPLOYEE
WHERE PROJECT.Department = EMPLOYEE.Department
AND           ProjectID IN  
               (SELECT PROJECT ID
                FROM PROJECT
                WHERE Department = 'Marketing')
ORDER BY ProjectID
```

I'm running it in Access as an SQL Query and the error that pops up says

```
Syntax error in query expression 'PROJECT.Department = EMPLOYEE.Department AND SELECT ProjectID, ProjectName, DepartmentPhone, EmployeeNumber, LastName, FirstName, EmployeePhone
FROM PROJECT, DEPARTMENT, EMPLOYEE
WHERE PROJECT.Department = EMPLOYEE.Department
AND           ProjectID IN  
               (SELECT PROJECT ID
                FROM PROJECT
                WHERE Department = 'Marketing')
ORDER BY ProjectID "
```

Without "AND" and everything past that it works just fine but displays all projects and not just those run by the Marketing Department. Please help!

Comment: Databases 101: Access <> SQL Server <> MySQL.

Comment: there are some joins missing I guess ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `IN` with select `IN (SELECT` you have to use exact one column, but I can see 2. Obviously you mean `IN (SELECT ID FROM PROJECT...`

P.S and yes,- you miss some joining...